# Where am I from?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Please don't edit this question (seriously). You have all the information you need to figure out where I am from. But I am going to be generous and give you some hints gradually if needed.

> First hint at 06-16 17:38 : It is cold here.

Comment: You're posting questions during the Germany - Poland football game at Euro 2016 so you are not from Germany nor Poland.

Comment: Good guess hahaha.

Comment: I just realized that I misread your question (or arguably it was poorly worded). I interpreted it such that you could answer the question without the hint. So I concluded that the answer must be buried somewhere within your SE profile which was a deep dark rabbit hole of mathematics...

Comment: @TTT Actually I gave the hint intentionally to complete the question in order to make it funny.

Comment: please give more downvotes without explanation.

Comment: I'm not one of the downvoters but I'm tempted to for a couple of reasons. Firstly hints on this site are supposed to help you find the solution but should not be essential. It should be reasonable to expect that someone can find the answer without them. This question does not work without the hint. Secondly, Puzzling Stack Exchange is intended to be a long-standing repository for good quality questions. In 13 hours, the exact time when you posted the hint will become obscured - it will just say 'edited 1 day ago'. Anyone subsequently coming across the question would be unable to answer it.

Comment: @GordonK Thank you very much for the explanation, noted for the future questions. BTW actually the second hint would be "be quick" but the answer was already found.

Comment: @GordonK if you mouse over the times it gives you exact datetime info (though I believe there is a scenario where short successive edits will merge into one edit so exact time might be a bit off), but regardless I agree with all your points. Also the question is literally where is X user located based of timezone differences and climate. That is not a very good basis for a puzzle in the first place as it involves a lot of guesswork. Also this is relevant http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/when-should-i-add-hints-to-my-puzzle

Comment: @GordonAllocman Yes, I saw that meta post just after I commented. And mouseover doesn't work on my phone!

Comment: Please don't trash your post after it's answered.

Comment: There's no need to be rude about it. People are downvoting your question because hints aren't supposed to be essential to answering the question, but here it is. It also seems like there are too many possible answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to change my guess and say you're from:

> <strike>Somewhere in Greenland</strike> Newfoundland

Reasoning:

> Your first hint is posted on the same day and 6 1/2 hours ahead of where I am (based on a 24 hour clock). This puts where you're from at UTC-2**.5**. [Link](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ndt) to where I got this answer. And Newfoundland is north enough to be considered cold.

EDIT: I think I got it. <strike>Otherwise, I'm still thinking about other ways to support my guess.</strike>

Comment: No, I am not from Greenland. I could be from Patagonia also.

Comment: I think since his time is -2.5 UTC. Which isn't a time zone as far as I know. Maybe I am wrong though

Comment: Actually, I noticed that too...there's a few half hour time zones but not UTC-2.5

Comment: You are close though.

Comment: Congratulations, you've got it.

Comment: I changed my answer...I think I got it but, not 100% sure. EDIT: Nvm yay xD

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you are from:

> Italy

It's a pretty thin argument, but:

> You posted this question with a link to an Italian site: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113810/how-to-cite-an-online-brochure

Though I don't think this fits your hint as it's currently 22 degrees Celsius there and that isn't a normal definition of "cold".